# Using QFuture to call a local class function

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a UI program in which i used `QFuture` to run a function in a different class that was heavy on processor etc. and caused my UI to crash, after using QFuture to thread this out it works fine, however I have another function that will need to be called right after however this one is within the same class as where I'm calling it from.

I have used the same code to do the second one but it just shows errors about `Timers` which I'm not even using, also I don't know if its right that I'm using `this` in the arguments:

```
future = new QFuture<void>;

*future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &GUI::test);
```

test being a local function, is it something to do with the fact that I can't have two concurrent::run calls or something, I've tried looking at the documentation which hasn't helped unfortunately

basically when this is called the UI locks up and I get some strange warnings, and I thought the point of threading it was that the UI wouldn't crash

Comment: Qt widgets have thread affinity, do you do anything in test that must be done on the GUI thread, e.g. access any widget's state? That would explain the locking up. Oh, and the point of threading is that the UI shouldn't be blocked by long operations, not that it doesn't crash. Crashing when threading is far too easy ;)

Comment: I update the scene for a qGraphicsView?, any ideas why i might be getting this error though when i do not do anything with timers `QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread`

Comment: I would guess that something you do internally starts a timer.

Comment: so how can i stop it if i have no object to call stop on since i never created one, and i use the exact same code as above to call a different function and it doesn't mention timers at all *note* timers are not used in either function

Comment: any suggestions on this ?

Comment: seriously no ideas from anyone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess on this.

I'm guessing that you have the following situation. (Note: understanding the situation you're in is very useful when trying to come up with a solution for a problem. Often it turns out that the OP is going about something in a fundamentally wrong way and should be doing something entirely different.)

You have a GUI. You have an operation that takes a long time, which you want to run in a worker thread. And at the end of the long operation, you need to call a function on the GUI thread, probably to update the GUI or something similar.

So you launch the background task using QtConcurrent::run(&someObject, &SomeObject::task). Then you need some way to be notified, on the GUI thread, when the task is completed.

The correct way to do this is to attach a QtFutureWatcher to the future returned from run() and connect a slot on your GUI class to its finished signal. Qt's signal mechanism will ensure that the slot is called on the right thread.

Comment: sorry, my code wasnt complete the function that takes a long time is run on a thread using the code i showed above i have a watcher waiting for the finished signal, when it gets that it calls a slot which uses the same code as above again that calls a function thats updating a Scene on my UI with a watcher waiting for finished signal again, on finish a slot is called that just std::cout a finished message but i get a ui crash on the second function that adds to a scene on my ui???

Comment: Maybe you're not allowed to update the Scene in a worker thread? I don't know enough about Qt scene graphs.

Comment: yea maybe not ... it would explain why the ui just says not responding even though its been threaded. any ideas on the Timer warning i mention in the comment above?

Comment: Do you still get the warning if you make sure not to call anything on  a bad thread? If so, see if you can maybe set a breakpoint on the Qt function that emits warnings, run under the debugger, and do a backtrace from the warning emission to your code to find out what is the root cause of the warning, i.e. which function that you use internally starts the timer. Then you can try to understand where that timer is created and make sure the two events happen on the same thread.

Comment: i appriciate the help but theres just some issues going on with my Ui functionality and threading, iv asked about 5 questions on here about this problem and no one can come up with a solution that works... think the problem now is that apparently you cant do anything ui which isnt main thread but its the ui stuff thats takes ages and needs threading soooooo i have no idea what to do tbh i dont believe thats the case but no one seems to know ...